# PSNR/MSE calculation for two images

Tags: python, image, rgb, mse

I want to write a function which is getting two images reference and encoded and evaluates the (R)MSE and PSNR for each component (R, G, B, Y, Cb, Cr). For that, I am extracting all components and then I am converting the RGB -> YCbCr. I want to calculate the (R)MSE and PSNR without using a built-in function.

```
import os, sys, subprocess, csv, datetime
from PIL import Image

############ Functions Definitions ############

# Extracts the values of the R, G, B components of each pixel in the input file and calculates the Y, Cb, Cr components returning a dictionary having a key tuple with the coordinates of
 the pixes and values the values of each R, G, B, Y, Cb, Cr components
def rgb_calc(ref_file):
  img = Image.open(ref_file)
  width, height = img.size
  print(width)
  print(height)
  rgb_dict = {}
  for x in range (width):
    for y in range(height):
      r, g, b = img.load()[x, y]
      lum = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
      cb = 128 - 0.168736 * r - 0.331264 * g + 0.5 * b
      cr = 128 + 0.5 * r - 0.418688 * g - 0.081312 * b
      print("X {} Y {} R {} G {} B {} Y {} Cb {} Cr {}".format(x, y, r, g, b, lum, cb, cr))
      rgb_dict[(x, y)] = (r, g, b, lum, cb, cr)
  return rgb_dict

############ MAIN FUNCTION ############

r_img = sys.argv[1]
p_img = sys.argv[2]

ref_img = Image.open(r_img)
proc_img = Image.open(p_img)

resolution_ref = ref_img.size
resolution_proc = proc_img.size

if resolution_ref == resolution_proc:
  ycbcr_ref = rgb_calc(r_img)
  ycbcr_proc = rgb_calc(proc_img)
else:
  exit(0)
```

I want to write a new function and eventually output the average PSNR for each component and an average for the whole image.

**Is there a way to speed up my process?**

Currently, the `img.load()` is taking around 10-11 seconds per 8Mpx image and the creation of the dictionary additional 6 seconds. So only extracting these values and creating two dictionaries is taking already 32 seconds.

Comment: just in case: what is your python version?

Comment: do you need those `r`, `g`, `b` values in the dict, or could you do without them?

Comment: one way to speed things up could be to let Pillow (`PIL`) make the conversion from RGB to YCbCr. The only drawback seems to be that the resulting values are rounded to integers. If you need precision, this may not be feasible. Furthermore the coefficients might not be the same. But if the rounding and the possibly different coefficients are not a problem, this could give quite a speed-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do the `img.load()` outside the loop!

```
def rgb_calc(ref_file):
  img = Image.open(ref_file)
  width, height = img.size
  print(width)
  print(height)
  rgb_dict = {}
  rgb = img.load()
  for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
      r, g, b = rgb[x, y]
      lum = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b
      cb = 128 - 0.168736 * r - 0.331264 * g + 0.5 * b
      cr = 128 + 0.5 * r - 0.418688 * g - 0.081312 * b
      rgb_dict[(x, y)] = (r, g, b, lum, cb, cr)
  return rgb_dict
```

But this is only the start. The next thing I would do (but I'm no expert!) is use a numpy array instead of a dict indexed by (x, y).

---

EDIT

I tried to speed things up using a numpy ndarray (N-dimensional array), but was stuck, so asked a specific question, and got the resolving answer (a ×15 speed-up!):
[numpy.ndarray with shape (height, width, n) from n values per Image pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027266/numpy-ndarray-with-shape-height-width-n-from-n-values-per-image-pixel/53027391?noredirect=1#comment92963342_53027391)

Here it is, adapted to your needs, and with some detail of your original code fixed:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def get_rgbycbcr(img: Image.Image):
    R, G, B = np.array(img).transpose(2, 0, 1)[:3]  # ignore alpha if present
    Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
    Cb = 128 - 0.168736 * R - 0.331264 * G + 0.5 * B
    Cr = 128 + 0.5 * R - 0.418688 * G - 0.081312 * B
    return np.array([R, G, B, Y, Cb, Cr], dtype=float).transpose(2, 1, 0)

r_img = sys.argv[1]
p_img = sys.argv[2]

ref_img  = Image.open(r_img)
proc_img = Image.open(p_img)

resolution_ref  = ref_img.size
resolution_proc = proc_img.size

if resolution_ref == resolution_proc:
    ycbcr_ref  = get_ycbcr(ref_img) 
    ycbcr_proc = get_ycbcr(proc_img)
else:
    exit(0)
```

What you are left with now is a numpy array of shape `(width, height, 6)`. I don't think you need the original RGB data in there (you can get it anytime from the image) – you can change the code reducing 6 to 3, in case. You can index, e.g., `ycbcr_ref` like this: `ycbcr_ref[x, y]` and get a list of length 6 containing the same data you had in tuples stored in a dictionary. But you can extract slices, specifically along this “axis” (numpy terminology) of length 6, and do operations on them, like

```
y_mean = ycbcr_ref[:, :, 3].mean()
```

It's absolutely worthwhile to learn how to use [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/index.html)!

I'll help you with one detail: Unless you tell it otherwise, numpy stores data with the slowest varying index (AKA axis) first and the fastest varying last. Since images are stored by rows, unless you do a `transpose()` an image read into numpy will have to be indexed like `arr[y, x]`. Transposing will shuffle axes. In your case you have 3 axes numbered 0, 1, 2. E.g., `.transpose(1, 0, 2)` will exchange x and y, while `.transpose(2, 0, 1)` will make the pixel channels the “outer” (slowest varying) index.

Comment: thanks for the hint, this actually saved around 6 seconds per image processing and I have just found out that my function can't handle jpg files and crashes with the following error message: "AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'". But the most important part is the MSE calculation per component. I think the easiest solution is to convert the jpg image into png and then run against the png.

Comment: I think you should change `ycbcr_proc = rgb_calc(proc_img)` to `ycbcr_proc = rgb_calc(p_img)` to fix that error - or else pass to `rgb_calc()` the results of `Image.open()`, without re-opening the files inside the function (probably better)